# How can i avoid making doubles when using subdivision modifier?

Tags: modeling

Hello i learning blender and have a question about the subdivision modifier. I make the model as on the picture. I have a subdivision modifier on it. 
I know i can use loop cuts to make the rods not pointy, but the problem is when i use it they create doubles, i dont know if doubles is so big problem, but i heard its not really wanted. I allso know i can slide the loop cut just a little bit before the end edge and then it will not make any double, but it feels a bit not totally correct doing it that way, i dont know lol?.
My question is if this is the way of doing this? or are there better ways?[image]

Comment: something has to be clarified. Doubles are vertices (points) at the exact same position (X,Y,Z).

Comment: Creating loop cuts (sometimes called proximity or holding cuts in this situation) close to the edge is the proper way to accomplish what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Doubles are generally a bad thing, as they are difficult to properly select, can cause artefacts, prevent cleaning whole model with *Remove Doubles* and can cause accidental unwanted merge when moving things with auto merge on. Sliding the loopcut just a bit before the end instead is totally fine way to do that, i really don't see what incorrect you see in that.

Answer (score 0):

Doubles are not allways forbidden. That can be a choice.

But here you can also simply remove the bottom faces of the bar.

[image]

Edit : as i suppose the bar will go throught the sit.
Another point for the top of the bars : you could separate the bars from the back in order to avoid the effect you have here at the junction of them.

Edit2 : as a suggestion, another modeling approach, from left to right :

- Cube with a bevel modifier
- Cylinder with array
- Applied modifier then joined meshes
- Mesh deform modifier

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> are there better ways?

you could use a bevel modifier with a vertex group made of the vertices of the pointy edges so that it won't bevel the whole mesh.

Comment: Thanks for all answers, i am still at learning in blender, so thats why i ask this question, to avoid learning wrong methods, but seems like there are different ways of fixing this. Did not think about i could just delete the bottom face, good idea.

Answer (score 0):

All the previous answers would work, additionally, IF you are planning to apply the subdivision modifier, you can create the doubles, then apply the modifier, then select these vertices, and press <kbd>W</kbd> then choose remove doubles. As I said, this would be a solution only if you are planning to apply the Subdivision Modifier. If this is not the case, you can use an Edge Split modifier, it should be after the Subdivision modifier in the stack, and give it a propper maximum angle, just keep in mind, this will affect your entire object.